# Delete specific paragraphs based on substring using word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to search for a specific string in every paragraph throughout the document and delete paragraphs that don't contain that string.

I tried this macro code:

```
Sub DeleteParagraphContainingString()

    Dim search As String
    search = "delete me"

    Dim para As Paragraph
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

        Dim txt As String
        txt = para.Range.Text

        If Not InStr(LCase(txt), search) Then
            para.Range.Delete
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

It deletes paragraphs although it has that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the code.  The change that made the code work was separating the If statement from the InStr() function.  Performing the check first in a separate line then test the result.

**TESTED:**

```
Sub DeleteParagraphContainingString()

    Dim check As Boolean
    Dim search As String
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim tempStr As String
    Dim txt As String

    search = "delete me"

    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        txt = para.Range.Text
        tempStr = LCase(txt)
        check = InStr(tempStr, search)

        If check = False Then
            para.Range.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**BEFORE:**

[image: BEFORE]

**AFTER:**

[image: AFTER]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for this piece of code. Just had to replace the False parameter with True. Otherwise, it would keep only the very paragraphs that contain the string "delete me" it was intended to vaporize.

See below:

Sub DeleteParagraphContainingString()

```
Dim check As Boolean
Dim search As String
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim tempStr As String
Dim txt As String

search = "delete me"

For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    txt = para.Range.Text
    tempStr = LCase(txt)
    check = InStr(tempStr, search)

    If check = True Then
        para.Range.Delete
    End If
Next
```

End Sub